# Expert f# script compile oddity

Tags: f#

On page 209 - 210 there is an extended example (see below) (I'm using F# 4.5).

In summary what I don't understand is: if I type each statement individually, there is a declaration that raises an error. If I submit the whole script at once, with the functions that come after the declaratation that raises the error, everything is OK. So what happens in interactive when I submit all the statements as a batch? Does the function that follows the error get used to create a specific version of the potential generic? The ionide hints do not show a generic for the whole script.

In detail (sorry it's so long)
If you execute each of the statements in order upto and including the declaration of `formatP` , (or paste all of them upto and including `formatP`  at once - e.g. select and alt-enter with ionide in vs code) in interactive, it produces an error:

```
    binary.fsx(67,5): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'formatP' has been inferred to have generic type
        val formatP : ((int * bool) list -> '_a -> unit) when '_a :> OutState
    Either make the arguments to 'formatP' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

- if you paste all of the script including the functions which follow `formatP`

```ml
let writeData file data =
    use outStream = BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(file))
    formatP data outStream

let readData file =
    use inStream = BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(file))
    formatU inStream
```

it works without error.

**Given that compilation order is important - what is happening here?**

i.e. why do the functions that are declared after `formatP`  allow the function to compile.

Whole script - which functions without error (It's a bit long - but because I really don't understand the issue, I'm not sure what I can remove to create an accurate example illustrating what is happening.
I guess I could drop `formatU` and `readData`? (which have the same relationship) but they are needed to make the last 2 stamenets work which sahows that the code does complie and execute as expected):

```ml
open System.IO

type OutState = BinaryWriter
type InState = BinaryReader
type Pickler<'T> = 'T -> OutState -> unit
type Unpickler<'T> = InState -> 'T

// P is the suffix for pickling and U is the suffix for unpickling
let byteP (b : byte) (st : OutState) = st.Write(b)
let byteU (st : InState) = st.ReadByte()

let boolP b st = byteP (if b then 1uy else 0uy) st
let boolU st = let b = byteU st in (b = 1uy)

let int32P i st =
    byteP (byte (i &&& 0xFF)) st
    byteP (byte ((i >>> 8) &&& 0xFF)) st
    byteP (byte ((i >>> 16) &&& 0xFF)) st
    byteP (byte ((i >>> 24) &&& 0xFF)) st

let int32U st =
    let b0 = int (byteU st)
    let b1 = int (byteU st)
    let b2 = int (byteU st)
    let b3 = int (byteU st)
    b0 ||| (b1 <<< 8) ||| (b2 <<< 16) ||| (b3 <<< 24)

let tup2P p1 p2 (a, b) (st : OutState) =
    (p1 a st : unit)
    (p2 b st : unit)
let tup3P p1 p2 p3 (a, b, c) (st : OutState) =
    (p1 a st : unit)
    (p2 b st : unit)
    (p3 c st : unit)
let tup2U p1 p2 (st : InState) =
    let a = p1 st
    let b = p2 st
    (a, b)
let tup3U p1 p2 p3 (st : InState) =
    let a = p1 st
    let b = p2 st
    let c = p3 st
    (a, b, c)

/// Outputs a list into the given output stream by pickling each element via f.
/// A zero indicates the end of a list, a 1 indicates another element of a list.
let rec listP f lst st =
    match lst with
    | [] -> byteP 0uy st
    | h :: t -> byteP 1uy st; f h st; listP f t st

// Reads a list from a given input stream by unpickling each element via f.
let listU f st =
    let rec loop acc =
        let tag = byteU st
        match tag with
        | 0uy -> List.rev acc
        | 1uy -> let a = f st in loop (a :: acc)
        | n -> failwithf "listU: found number %d" n
    loop []

type format = list<int32 * bool>

//the types in these two lines only get fully inferred if the lines after are part of the batch
//eh?
let formatP = listP (tup2P int32P boolP)
let formatU = listU (tup2U int32U boolU)
//IE if you only run to here it is an error

let writeData file data =
    use outStream = BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(file))
    formatP data outStream

let readData file =
    use inStream = BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(file))
    formatU inStream
//If you run to here it does not error

writeData "out.bin" [(102, true); (108, false)] ;;
readData "out.bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here, only one of which I can fully explain.

The first is the F# value restriction. In this case, the compiler infers that `listP` is a generic function, which also makes the value `formatP` generic. But F# doesn't allow a generic value in this situation, so a compiler error occurs. However, when `writeData` is present, `formatP` is no longer generic, so the compiler error disappears. You can see a very similar situation explained in detail [here](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#fs-value-restriction).

But why does the compiler think `listP` is generic in the first place? I'm not sure about this. It infers that `st` must be compatible with `OutState`, which is correct from an object-oriented point of view. But it expresses this as a generic constraint, using `st : #OutState` instead of just `st : OutState`. (F# calls this a "[flexible type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types)".) This generic constraint then cascades to `formatP`, causing the problem you reported. Someone with more knowledge of the F# compiler might be able to explain this.

---

Here's a very small example that exhibits the same behavior:

```ml
type Example() = class end

let alpha (_ : Example) =
    ()

let beta f x =
    alpha (f x)

let gamma = beta id

// let delta = gamma (Example())
```

The compiler infers a generic type for `beta`, which makes `gamma` illegal when `delta` is commented out.

To make matters stranger, the same problem occurs even if I explicitly annotate `beta` so it's not generic:

```ml
let beta (f : Example -> Example) (x : Example) =
    alpha (f x)
```

So the compiler thinks `gamma` is generic even when `beta` definitely isn't generic. I don't know why that is.

Comment: interesting - note that `let gamma t = beta id t` is also fine without delta - and is not generic : > `let gamma t = beta id t;;`
results in the type `val gamma : t:Example -> unit` so there seems to be no generic anywhere. The bit I have trouble with is well illustrated in your example - in theory compilation order is important - but with delta included - a following statement sorts out the type of an earlier one... just seems weird.

Comment: Yes, the F# value restriction definitely takes some getting used to, but is also easily avoided most of the time. Generic functions are fine, but the compiler is suspicious of generic values (["point free" style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)). Adding explicit arguments, as you suggest, avoids the problem. Similarly, once the compiler can see that `delta` is not generic, it can safely assume that `gamma` wasn't intended to be generic either.